# Toggle between texts values on Button click

Tags: android, text, android-button

I need to be able to toggle between two text values of "Hello world!" and "Hello!!!". I know this is going to be incredibly simple, but as I'm very new to programming so bear with me.  Thanks in advance.

```
package edu.purdue.cnit355_lab1;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    private Button HelloButton;
    private TextView Message;
    private OnClickListener HelloButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Message.setText("Hello!!!");
            }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HelloButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HelloButton);
        Message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MessageText); 
        HelloButton.setOnClickListener(HelloButtonListener);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My `layout.main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/HelloButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_button_label"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Hello Button</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="hello_button_label">Say &quot;Hello!&quot;.</string>
```

Comment: Code it wouldn't let me paste. import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (Message.getText().equals("Hello World")) {
          Message.setText("Hello!!!");
        } else {
          Message.setText("Hello World");
        }
   }
```

you should also consider getting the string value using 
`getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world)` instead of using them hard coded.

And try to avoid naming variables with uppercase like `Message` as they can be mistaken for objects.

Comment: I will try this shortly, but this looks like a viable solution. I was thinking I needed an if else statement, but wasn't sure how to implement it. This code was copied and pasted from my assignment, but I appreciate you letting me know not to name variables in uppercase.

Comment: I did so, but now I'm getting an error on the line of code that says "  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {" It is telling me that I need the Bundle savedInstanceState enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. You can add some flag to toogle between your strings. Something like this:

```
private Strig[] hello = new String[]{"Hello World", "Hello!"}; 
private int toggleFlag = 0;
```

In your onClick method:

```
Message.setTex(hello[toogleFlag]);
toggleFlag ^= 1;   // exclusive OR
```

Comment: I'm sure this code works, but it is way above my skill level.  I'm very appreciative of your feedback, but the other answer I received looks more like what I was trying to do.